# Excel VBA "Find" Command

Tags: excel, vba

I need to retrieve a value from a cell, then find that value in a named range (GasDip) and return the value from the cell to the right of the found cell to the current worksheet.  This is what I have:

```
Dim GasDipVal As String
Dim DipAMount As Integer

GasDipVal = Range("gasdipamt").Value

Application.Goto Reference:="GASDIP"
Selection.Find(What:="GasDipval", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
    :=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
DipAMount = ActiveCell.Value
Application.Goto Reference:="DATE"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 11).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = DipAMount
```

The error occurs when it reached the "Selection.Find" command.   It won't recognize the "GasDipValue"    If I search for a static number that I put inside of qutes, it works.

Please help!!   Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Selection.Find(What:=GasDipval, ...`

Comment: When you enclose the name of the variable inside `" "`, you're not using the value of that variable, but it's litteral name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could probably use the function [VLOOKUP](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) to do the job for you.